# HQL subquery does not see the table

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am using Hibernate 3.5.6. 
I try to do subquery like this:

```
List<TUserProfile> results = getHibernateTemplate()
                .find("from TUserProfile as user where defaultCustomerId<>'BANK' " +
                        " and (user.userId,user.entity) "+
                                "in (select gua.userId,gua.entity from TGlobalUsersAuthorization as gua )",
                        new Object[] {});
```

I want to see users that are also in TGlobalUsersAuthorization.

TGlobalUsersAuthorization is a class I added like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_GLOBAL_USERS_AUTHORIATION")
public class TGlobalUsersAuthorization{

@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private String userId;
@Column(name = "ENTITY")
private String entity;
@Column(name = "ENTITY_CUSTOMER")
private String entityCustomer;
@Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
private String groupId;
@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
private String cutomerId;

public TGlobalUsersAuthorization(){
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getEntity() {
    return entity;
}
public void setEntity(String entity) {
    this.entity = entity;
}
public String getEntityCustomer() {
    return entityCustomer;
}
public void setEntityCustomer(String entityCustomer) {
    this.entityCustomer = entityCustomer;
}
public String getGroupId() {
    return groupId;
}
public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
}
public String getCutomerId() {
    return cutomerId;
}
public void setCutomerId(String cutomerId) {
    this.cutomerId = cutomerId;
}
}
```

`T_GLOBAL_USERS_AUTHORIATION` is a table.

`TUserProfile` is another entity. This part works - before the subquery it was OK.

I get exception :

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

What is missing here?

Thank you.

Kirill.

Comment: Not an answer but another important hint. Be aware of the fact that an in statement of a query is not allowed to ever be empty.

Comment: Can you post the generated query?

Answer (score 0):

This was a typo mistake.
Thank you for the answers.